# arbitrary size tuple with first element type fixed

Tags: scala

Say I have two lists

```
val L1 = List[(Int, Int)]((1,1), (2,2))
val L2 = List[(Int, Int, Int)]((1,1,1), (2,2,2))
```

Now I want to make a function `func` that takes in an Int value `i` and all items from both lists where the first element matches `i`. One way is

```
def func(i:Int) = {
  L1.collect.collect{case any if any._1 != i => any}
  L2.collect.collect{case any if any._1 != i => any}
}
```

considering that the two lines are so similar, it would be nice if code can be shortened. I am thinnking of some way where I could pass `L1` (and `L2`) as a parameter to `func`. The function should not know in advance how many elements the tuple will have, just that the first element is `Int`.

Is this possible?

[EDIT: I think the question was not clear enough. My apologies.]

Here is what I want to do. I would like to do this on more than two lists, say n, by calling `func` several times, once for each list.

```
  L1 = L1.collect.collect{case any if any._1 != i => any}
  L2 = L2.collect.collect{case any if any._1 != i => any}
  ...
  Ln = Ln.collect.collect{case any if any._1 != i => any}
```

where each `L1`, `L2`, ... `Ln` are lists of tuples with first element `Int`

[EDIT2]

In the above, `L1` could be list of `(Int, String)`, `L2` could be of `(Int, Int, Int)`, etc. The only guarantee is that the first element is `Int`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  def func(i:Int, lst: List[Product]) = {
    lst.filter(_.productElement(0) == i)
  }
```

Edited as per your edit & Dan's comment above.

Comment: thanks. I was not aware or `productIterator`. Seems to solve my problem. The list was just to give an example to do something with the tuples (for lack of better ones). I really needed to figure out how to handle tuples in a generic way.

Comment: I don't think what I want to do is possible but this seems to be a generic way to deal with tuples. What I want is to reassign L1, L2, etc.

Comment: @Jus12 you could define your lists as `var`s rather than `val`s, then use `L1 = func(i, L1)` etc, if that's what you want

Answer (score 2):

Any `Tuple` (or, indeed, any case class) is a `Product`, so you can use the product iterator as a way to handle tuples of indeterminate size:

```
val x = (1,1,1,1)
x.productIterator forall {_ == 1} //returns true
```

as Product is a common supertype for the elements of both lists, you can simply concatenate them and filter:

```
val list1 = List((1,1), (2,2))
val list2 = List((1,1,1), (2,2,2))

(list1 ::: list2) filter {_.productIterator forall {_ == 1}}
//returns List[Product with Serializable] = List((1,1), (1,1,1))
```

**UPDATE**

To filter just a single list on the first element of contained products:

```
val list1 = List((1,1), (2,2))
list1 filter {_.productIterator.next() == 1}
```

Comment: That will return lists where all the tuple elements equal `i`, I think the OP wants the tuples where the first item in the tuple is `i` and other elements can be whatever, in which case you can use Product.productElement(0) to get the first item for any Tuple.

Comment: I guess I can do `x.productIterator.next == 1` for each tuple